# How to get the path when executing a program?

Tags: python

(Translated from Chinese using DeepL)
I want to get the path where the python program is located when it is executed from the command line.

For example, I have stored the program in `C:\` and executed the following command using the command line:

```
d:
python "c:\xxx.py"
```

At this point, I want to get the path `D:\` in my program.

I have written the following code:

```py
import sys
print(sys.argv[0])
```

and saved it as `cb.py` under `C:\`.
Next, I executed `python "c:\cb.py"` under `D:\` and got the same output `c:\main.py`, but I was expecting `d:\`.
[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jQGi2.png)

Comment: Do you mean [`os.getcwd()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.getcwd)?

Comment: you can also do `os.path.abspath('.')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I referenced a comment that

```py
os.getcwd()
```

can achieve the results I want!
Thanks @bereal

Comment: Friendly reminder that you should be able to accept your own answer by now. Do so by clicking the v-shaped button to its left.

Answer (score -2):

You can try:

```
import sys, os

file = sys.argv[0]
pathname = os.path.dirname(file)
print (f"Path is {os.path.abspath(pathname)} ")
print (f"file is {file} ")
```

Comment: OP wrote how `sys.argv[0]` does not do what they want.

Comment: Working directory and file directory are not the same.